# Find out what causes freezes of my phone

Tags: system-freeze

My phone (Elephone P9000 lite) behaves really strange since some time: Every now and then it freezes for about 1-2 seconds.

There are two different types of freezes:

1. The touchscreen does not react to a tap on the screen (e.g. when playing a game, there is still movement of units, etc)
2. Full freeze - input not working, audio stops, app "paused" (e.g. when playing a game, the movement of unit stops)

I can't identify a specific cause for the problem, i.e. it can happen when I play a game, watch a video, or listen to music (also occurs when the screen is off).

So my question is: Is there a way to find out what causes this problem?

Bonus question: Should I worry about the problem (i.e. could it indicate a hardware/software problem that could lead to a bigger issue)?

- Phone: P9000_lite
- Android: 6.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes, Lower-Spec devices Run out of RAM, **but don't know what to remove to clear it** So it will either cause a wedge/freeze, or restart zygote by accident (which restarts the phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very general but I can give you some common reasons why phones freeze and some troubleshoot steps.

- Do a restart by holding the power button and then press restart.
- Find out which apps are using the most system resources and unistall them, then check if that fixes the problem. (Common apps like this are Facebook and Facebook Messenger). [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mem.usage) app can help you fix RAM issues.
- If you see any errors during the crashes post them in the comments or edit the original post
- Last option would be to [factory reset](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/elephone/elephone-p9000-lite/) the phone but as the website says, all described operations you are doing at your own risk.

p.s. also, its not a good idea to post your build number on a public forum.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested steps (I'll try them) and the hint regarding the build number, was not aware that it's not wise to post it publicly.

Comment: No problem. Try them and if they help you make sure to mark my question as the answer, so other people know.

Comment: Good general troubleshooting advice, but I disagree strongly with the build number advice. There's no particular security risk and it's useful troubleshooting info for diagnostic build specific bugs.

Comment: The problem is gone. But I don't know why... before I had enough time to try the suggested steps, there were no more freezes. There were updates for Facebook and Facebook Messenger, so I suspect that a previous version of one of these apps caused the problem. Therefore, I'll mark your answer as helpful since the second point would have solved the problem for sure. Thanks!